# Generating a list of all possible combinations satisfying a constraint

Tags: list-manipulation

Defining

```
\Psi=A_n1.B_n2.C_n3.D_n4.E_n5.F_n6
```

where the dot means some kind of product that I need to use in my full code. How do I generate a list of all possible terms like the above where `n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6` can only be `-1,0,1` and are constrained by `n1+n2+n3+n4+n5+n6=3`?

For example, the list would have a term of the form

```
list1={..., A_0.B_0.C_0.D_1.E_1.F_1,...}
```

Edit: I also need that each term in the list comes multiplied with an arbitrary coefficient numbered by the position of the term in the list. So if the above example denotes the 15th term, the list I want would be

```
list1={...,a_15 A_0.B_0.C_0.D_1.E_1.F_1,...}
```

where `a_15` is an arbitrary coefficient.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid conflicts with built-in Mathematica symbols, do not use capital letters for user-defined symbols. For example, `C`, `D`, and `E` have predefined meanings. I have used `{a, b, c, d, e, f}` and `k` for the arbitrary coefficients.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

(Format[#[n_]] := Subscript[#, n]) & /@
  {a, b, c, d, e, f, k};

indices = Select[Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, 6], Total[#] == 3 &];

n = Length[indices]

(* 50 *)

list1 = MapIndexed[
   k[#2[[1]]]*
     CenterDot @@ #1 &, ((Transpose[{{a, b, c, d, e, f}, #}] & /@ 
       indices) /. {sym_Symbol, i_} :> sym[i])];

Length[list1]

(* 50 *)
```

The first few terms of `list1` are

```
list1[[1 ;; 6]]
```

[image]

You need to define the operation for `CenterDot`. By default, the coefficients `k` display after the `CenterDot` products.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way to get the index list (all possible 6-tuples of `{-1, 0, 1}` that add up to 3) is to use [`IntegerPartitions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html) with `{-1, 0, 1}` as the third argument and take permutations of each partition:

```
ip = Join @@ (Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[3, {6}, {-1, 0, 1}]);
```

This approach is faster than using `Tuples` and filtering the results. When sorted, `ip` and Bob Hanlon's `indices` are the same:

```
Sort @ ip == Sort @ indices
```

> True

First, use Bob Hanlon's suggestion to use `Subscript` for formatting indexed variables:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, e, f, k]

vars = {a, b, c, d, e, f, k};

(Format[#[n_]] := Subscript[#, n]) & /@ vars;
```

To get the lists of indexed variables use a combination of [`Inner`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html) + [`CenterDot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CenterDot.html) and multiply it with `Array[k, Length @ ip]`:

```
l1 = Array[k, Length @ ip] Map[Inner[# @ #2 &, Most @ vars, #, CenterDot] &] @ ip;

Length @ l1
```

> ```
> 50
> ```

```
l1 // Short[#, 3] &
```

[image]

Comment: If I try to apply a function in `l1`, Mathematica does nothing. But if I copy the output of `l1` and then apply the function in this copied output, Mathematica recognizes and does what I expect. Do you know what is happening?

Comment: Also, I then ask if `l1=== copied output` and the answer is False. I have no idea what is happening, I Quit all cells and the problem still persists.